# Why is the git pre-push not firing off before the push?

Tags: git, shell

I have created a pre-push file and saved it into the .git/hooks folder. What seems to be going on is that the push is still making the call to the server even though I put in an echo statement and an ***exit 1*** call. When I perform a git push call I can see the server message then my echo statement.

Shouldn't the push process stop immediately and not establish a connection to the remote server if the first line of the pre-push file is ***exit 1***?

What am I missing here on this hook? The only thing that I would expect to see is my Hello there message and nothing else.

```
echo "Hello there"
exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't have the complete answer but this is what I have figured out.

Despite getting the banner message from the remote server the pre-push does stop the process from pushing to the server upon exit 1. It is misleading only because I am seeing the banner message but it is working.

Something should be documented in the git docs on why a connection is established at all for a pre-push before the push has been given the go ahead.

Comment: I agree that the documentation should be improved. It's quite necessary to establish the connection first, though, and a bit of thought will immediately show *why:* the pre-push hook gets not only the foreign Git's ref-name, it also gets the corresponding hash ID. The only entity that *has* that information—at least, *correct* information—is the foreign Git itself. So there must be a connection established, with data flowing, at this point.