# Git hook before pre-push?

Tags: git

I'd like to have a git hook that checks if there is a connection to the remote server and if not tries switching the remote to another server (in my specific instance, it would set up ssh port forwarding and switch the origin URL to use localhost). I tried to do this as a `pre-push` hook, but (as noted in the [`pre-push.sample`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample) file and discovered in, e.g., [Why is the git pre-push not firing off before the push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072578/why-is-the-git-pre-push-not-firing-off-before-the-push)), there is an attempt by `git push` to establish a connection before the `pre-push` script is run. So, my question is, is there something like a pre-`pre-push` hook that could be used that can be run before a connection is established?

At the moment, I just manually set up the port forwarding and have a different named `remote` with the localhost URL, but I'd prefer, if possible, for this to be automated.

Comment: I've never used the pre-push, but you can also use the .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option I've gone for at the moment is to basically create a script that wraps git and does certain things if it is called with the `push` argument. I.e., I've created an executable bash script called `git` that I've placed in `${HOME}/.local/bin`, which contains:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# set the actual git executable
GIT_EXEC=/usr/bin/git

# check if any arguments have been passed
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  # if trying to push, do some stuff
  if [ "$1" = "push" ]; then
    # do stuff pre-push
    ...

    # run git
    $GIT_EXEC "$@"

    # do stuff post push
    ...
  else
    # otherwise run git as normal
    $GIT_EXEC "$@"
  fi
else
   # run git as normal
   $GIT_EXEC
fi
```

Note that this might potentially cause issues for other applications that use `git`, so be careful!